# Why Java security settings have blocked a local application from running?

Tags: java, html, security, applet

I have a simple test applet , supposed to HelloWorld (and works fine using appletviewer hHelloWorld.class from the command line), but when I try to view hHelloWorld.html in my browser, I get this message (from Java itself, as far as I can tell, not my Firefox or Chrome):

> "Your security settings have blocked a local application from running."

i can solve this problem reducing the security level of java but i want to run  without changing java security

Comment: yes sir its working when i change Security levels in the Java Control Panel but i don't want to change my Security manually

Comment: @BrianRoach actually i don't want to change user machine setting where he/she run the the applet

Comment: Why are you using an Applets in 2014?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson for uploading file

Comment: Why? HTML5 has great upload support, even for multiple files!

Answer (score 0):

Not getting any security prompts is an almost impossible demand. With the variety of OS, browsers and anti-viruses you can never know. However, there are a few methods in which you can reduce the amount of security prompts:

- self signed applets (self signing is what you did with the command prompt) are very likely to always show security prompts. You can buy an official SSL and it will reduce the amount of prompts significantly.
- If you are requiring "all-permissions" you'll get much more prompts than if you require "sandbox" permissions.

I highly recommend you to look at the following links:

SSL: [Where could I buy a valid SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404907/where-could-i-buy-a-valid-ssl-certificate)

permissions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html